# Qt Designer - clickable area to generate map

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, grid, qtablewidget

Using Python 2.7.3 and Qt Designer 4.8.2: I'm new to Qt, how may I create a simple grid area that is clickable to generate a map? The image below illustrates what I intend.

In essence my main issue is the grid area, I'm unable to see anything like 'off the shelf' within Qt.

[image]

Comment: Emz, there's nothing really to try - that's my point. I have stated this, i.e. "nothing off the shelf" within Qt. Perhaps I should have been more clear, apologies. The first thing that came to mind was simple buttons that change color but this is inefficient. I also have no example code of mouse-click-detection over a given area: an example would be great instead of simply whinging.

Comment: Emz, a specific example in Python - I do state this in my question - if you're unable to answer a question perhaps best not to try.

Answer (score 3):

The nearest equivalent would seem to be a [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html).

Below is a basic demo that should give you a start in the right direction:

[image: screenshot]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
# from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(rows, columns + 1, self)
        self.table.setSelectionMode(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.NoSelection)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.EditTrigger.NoEditTriggers)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(30)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setHidden(True)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(30)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setHidden(True)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(columns, 50)
        margin = self.table.palette().window().color()
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(columns + 1):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                if column < columns:
                    item.setBackground(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.white)
                else:
                    item.setBackground(margin)
                    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
                    item.setText('0x00')
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.table.itemPressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

    def handleItemPressed(self, item):
        columns = self.table.columnCount() - 1
        if item.column() < columns:
            margin = self.table.item(item.row(), columns)
            value = 1 << (7 - item.column())
            result = int(margin.text(), 16)
            if item.background().color() == QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.black:
                item.setBackground(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.white)
                result &= ~value
            else:
                item.setBackground(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.black)
                result |= value
            margin.setText(f'0x{result:02X}')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window(4, 8)
    window.resize(350, 175)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

One (clunky?) solution would be to draw your map image using a label widget with a pixmap set. You can achieve the click-ability by listening for `mousePressEvent` on that widget, upon which you can get a `QMouseEvent` object that contains mouse x, y position (both global and relative to the clicked widget). This can then be used to determine where on the image was clicked.